# How do I efficiently retrieve a non-initial slice of a Flywheel scan?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Given a large Dynamo table with lots of items, I would like to be able to start a scan and later resume iteration on it from an unrelated Python context, as if I had continued calling the `next()` of `gen()` on the scan itself.

What I am trying to avoid:

```
offset = 500
count = 25
scan_gen = engine.scan(AModel).gen()
for _ in range(offset):
   scan_gen.next()
results = [scan_gen.next() for _ in range(count)]
```

Because this would require restarting the scan from the top, every single time.

I see that the DynamoDB API normally works in a cursor-like fashion with the `LastEvaluatedKey` property: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Is there a way to use this to jump ahead in scan generator in Flywheel?

Failing that, is there a way to serialize the state of the generator? I have tried pickling the generator, and it causes `pickle.PicklingError` due to name resolution problems:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/dump_dynamo_result', 'wb') as out_fp:
...  pickle.dump(engine.scan(AModel).gen(), out_fp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.generator
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build the LastEvaulatedKey yourself and pass it in as the [ExclusiveStartKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ExclusiveStartKey) in another scan. It will basically be the key (hash or hash/range) of the last item that was evaluated -- i.e. the item that you want to start scanning from.

If you want to see what it looks like, do a Scan and set the limit to 2 or something small. You'll get a LastEvaluatedKey returned and you can examine it and determine how to build it yourself. Then, choose an item from your database from where you want to start your scan and create a LastEvaluatedKey out of it.

Comment: This question is specifically in regards to Flywheel:
http://flywheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

On further investigation, I'm fairly certain this isn't possible (or at least not via an obvious mechanism). Here's the Scan source code:
https://github.com/mathcamp/flywheel/blob/0.4.4/flywheel/query.py#L262